# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: calcmedii/CalcMediiApp?

Tags: java

Hello I'm a beginner with NetBeans. I'm using Netbeans 7.0.1 and I've recently started designing a simple program. When I try to run the program in NetBeans it shows the following errors in console:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: calcmedii/CalcMediiApp
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: calcmedii.CalcMediiApp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: calcmedii.CalcMediiApp.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

I should mention the code shows no compilation errors whatsoever, I've run this program, but after I've added some radio buttons and a jraddiobuttongroup and added some events that make some elements invisible and visible it displays these errors.

This is the only piece of code I've written before the error. The entire code of the program is huge so I'll just paste this bit which might cause these errors:

```
    private void jRadioButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    jLabel6.setVisible(true);
    jLabel7.setVisible(false);
    jLabel8.setVisible(false);
    jLabel9.setVisible(false);
    jLabel10.setVisible(false);
    jFormattedTextField4.setVisible(true);
    jFormattedTextField5.setVisible(false);
    jFormattedTextField6.setVisible(false);
    jFormattedTextField7.setVisible(false);
    jFormattedTextField8.setVisible(false);
}                                             

private void jRadioButton2ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                               
    jLabel6.setVisible(true);
    jFormattedTextField4.setVisible(true);
}                                              

private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    jLabel6.setVisible(false);
    jLabel7.setVisible(false);
    jLabel8.setVisible(false);
    jLabel9.setVisible(false);
    jLabel10.setVisible(false);
    jFormattedTextField4.setVisible(false);
    jFormattedTextField5.setVisible(false);
    jFormattedTextField6.setVisible(false);
    jFormattedTextField7.setVisible(false);
    jFormattedTextField8.setVisible(false);
}                                             

private void jRadioButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    jLabel6.setVisible(true);
    jLabel7.setVisible(true);
    jLabel8.setVisible(false);
    jLabel9.setVisible(false);
    jLabel10.setVisible(false);
    jFormattedTextField4.setVisible(true);
    jFormattedTextField5.setVisible(true);
    jFormattedTextField6.setVisible(false);
    jFormattedTextField7.setVisible(false);
    jFormattedTextField8.setVisible(false);
}                                             

private void jRadioButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    jLabel6.setVisible(true);
    jLabel7.setVisible(true);
    jLabel8.setVisible(true);
    jLabel9.setVisible(false);
    jLabel10.setVisible(false);
    jFormattedTextField4.setVisible(true);
    jFormattedTextField5.setVisible(true);
    jFormattedTextField6.setVisible(true);
    jFormattedTextField7.setVisible(false);
    jFormattedTextField8.setVisible(false);
}                                             

private void jRadioButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    jLabel6.setVisible(true);
    jLabel7.setVisible(true);
    jLabel8.setVisible(true);
    jLabel9.setVisible(true);
    jLabel10.setVisible(false);
    jFormattedTextField4.setVisible(true);
    jFormattedTextField5.setVisible(true);
    jFormattedTextField6.setVisible(true);
    jFormattedTextField7.setVisible(true);
    jFormattedTextField8.setVisible(false);
}                                             

private void jRadioButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    jLabel6.setVisible(true);
    jLabel7.setVisible(true);
    jLabel8.setVisible(true);
    jLabel9.setVisible(true);
    jLabel10.setVisible(true);
    jFormattedTextField4.setVisible(true);
    jFormattedTextField5.setVisible(true);
    jFormattedTextField6.setVisible(true);
    jFormattedTextField7.setVisible(true);
    jFormattedTextField8.setVisible(true);
}
```

Please help I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the class `CalcMediiApp` in the package `calcmedii` cannot be found. How is your main class named? I mean the class you run.

Comment: All source files for my program are in the package "calcmedii" including: CalcMediiApp and CalcMediiView

  The main frame window source is called "CalcMediiView.java"

Comment: Ok I have a "calcmedii" package which contains:
CalcMediiAboutBox.java
CalcMediiApp.java
CalcMediiView.java
JFrameHelp.java

Comment: If it is not a problem for you please zip the whole project and upload it somewhere. It is difficult to help otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks perfect. It has whatsoever nothing to do with your question. From the exception thrown you mentioned, it's clear that you have mistakenly changed your *package name* or *class name* . Make sure that your class `CalcMediiApp` is in the package `calcmedii`.

Comment: All source files for my program are in the package "calcmedii" including: CalcMediiApp and CalcMediiView